# How to give data an alias in an R package?

Tags: r, roxygen2

Giving a function in an R package an alias is straight forward. E.g.

```
#' @rdname my_function_name
my_alias <- my_function_name
```

How can the same be achieved for a data file contained within the package?

#### What I've tried so far

I do not know how to give a data file in an R package an alias. However, I could simply place the same file in the package twice, and just give it a different name the second time. This would have the obvious downside of taking up more space than necessary, so I would like to find a better approach if possible.

Comment: I think you can use `@aliases` followed by a space-separated set of aliases.

Comment: @Alexis actually, I jumped the gun. It doesn't seem to work. It doesn't error either. package_name::data_alias` returns  `Error: 'data_alias' is not an exported object from 'namespace:my_package'`

Comment: I'm not sure that works for any data included in a package. If you document the data with, for example `@name pkgdata`, `package_name::pkgdata` won't work either. Those names and aliases are only recognized when you search for them in the documentation.

Comment: Now I spoke a bit too soon. The `::` notation will work to find the data with the name it has in the actual `.rda` file, the documentation's names/aliases won't work.

Comment: @Alexis just to clarify, there is no way (as far as we know) to create an alias for a data file in a package? (Other than duplicating the actual data, giving the copy the desired name etc)

Comment: Not in a way that will be user-visible, at least AFAIK. I can think of a workaround if you want to use the alias internally, or access it with `:::`, but it would be pretty hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did manage to make my workaround user-visible,
but it feels *very*, **very** hacky.
It would look something like this:

```
#' @export pkgdata
makeActiveBinding("pkgdata", env = asNamespace("mypkg"), fun = function(ignored) {
    data("mydata", package = "mypkg", envir = environment())
    mydata
})
```

By specifying `envir = environment()` in the call to `data` we make sure that the data is loaded in the function's call environment,
so it can be subsequently returned.
After that, it seems like `mypkg::pkgdata` would work,
and if you define `pkgdata` in the `@aliases` of `mydata`,
even `R CMD check` passes?